# Соединение с mysql по ssh туннелю в Windows

Tags: php, mysql, windows, ssh

Есть сервер с `MySQL`, и к нему надо конектиться на клиенте созданном на `php devel studio`. Хочу сделать коннект через `ssh` туннель, на юниксе это можно сделать так:

```
shell_exec("ssh -f -L 127.0.0.1:3307:127.0.0.1:3306 user@remote.rjmetrics.com sleep 60 >> logfile");  
$db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "sqluser", "sqlpassword", "rjmadmin", 3307);
```

Но клиент будет работать на Windows, как можно сделать тоже самое без использования дополнительных прог? Либо возможно есть какой то компонент в `devel studio` для этой цели?

Comment: просто к слову: ssh — это вполне себе «дополнительная» программа.

Comment: Согласен, но под ними я имею в виду Putty, и всё остальное

Comment: Посмотрите лучше `Bitvise SSH Client`. На мой взгляд для таких штук гораздо круче какого-то putty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putty можно использовать из командной строки windows, что-то в таком духе:

```
shell_exec("putty.exe -ssh user@remote.rjmetrics.com -L 127.0.0.1:3307:127.0.0.1:3306");
```